# angular 6 create instance of TemplateRef

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, angular6

I have (angular 6) component and input parameter of `TemplateRef<any>` type

```
class TestComponent {
    @Input() tpl: TemplateRef<any>;
    ...
}
```

Now I want to create a test and I can't find the way how to create a template in test and set it as an input field.

In my HTML I have template like

```
<test>
    <ng-template #tpl>
        <div>OLOLO</div>
    </ng-template>
</test>
```

I need something like this

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
component.template = here I need instance of TemplateRef
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I didn't got why you are doing it this way, but if you want to access the template in spec file, instead of using input use `viewchild` in the component

so use code will be

```
class TestComponent {
  @ViewChild('tpl') public tpl: ElementRef;
  ...
}
```

and in spec.ts try this

```
it('should create', () => {
  console.log(component.tpl);
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```